# Can I dynamically define a Ruby method that takes a block?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

I know that I can dynamically define methods on a class using `define_method`, and that I specify the parameters this method takes using the arity of the block.

I want to dynamically define a method that accepts both optional parameters and a block. In Ruby 1.9, this is easy because passing a block to a block is now allowed.

Unfortunately, Ruby 1.8 doesn't allow this, so the following won't work:

```
#Ruby 1.8
class X
  define_method :foo do |bar, &baz|
    puts bar
    baz.call if block_given?
  end
end

x = X.new
x.foo("foo") { puts "called!"} #=> LocalJumpError: no block given
```

Replacing the explicit `block.call` with `yield` doesn't fix the problem either.
Upgrading to Ruby 1.9 is unfortunately not an option for me. Is this an intractable problem, or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works with Ruby 1.8.7, but not 1.8.6:

```
class X
  define_method(:foo) do |bar, &baz|
    puts bar
    baz.call if baz
  end
end
```

Testing with:

```
X.new.foo("No block")
X.new.foo("With block") { puts "  In the block!"}
p = proc {puts "  In the proc!"}
X.new.foo("With proc", &p)
```

gives:

```
No block
With block
  In the block!
With proc
  In the proc!
```

(with 1.8.6 it gives `syntax error, unexpected tAMPER, expecting '|'`.)

If you want optional arguments as well as block, you could try something like this:

```
class X
  define_method(:foo) do |*args, &baz|
    if args[0]
      bar = args[0]
    else
      bar = "default"
    end
    puts bar
    baz.call if baz
  end
end
```

testing with:

```
X.new.foo
X.new.foo { puts "  No arg but block"}
```

gives:

```
default
default
  No arg but block
```

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is use `class_eval` with a string instead of `define_method`. The downside to this (apart from not being as elegant) is that you lose lexical scoping. But this is often not needed.

Comment: Do I need to pass a string to class_eval? Can't I pass a block, which would keep the scoping?

Comment: @andrewdotnich Well, then you’re back to the problem of how are you going to define the method dynamically.

Comment: https://github.com/agrimm/zombie-chaser/blob/master/lib/zombie-chaser/chaser.rb has an example and a link to a blog post halfway down the file.